# Basic OR difference

Tags: python

I was doing some tests, when I tried:

```
len(pin) == (4 or 6)
```

Half of the tests failed.

However with :

```
(len(pin) == 4 or len(pin) == 6)
```

All the tests were passed.

I am unable to understand the difference that is between these two.
pin is usually a number like `1234` or `12345`.

Comment: Why downvote and duplicate? as this condtion `len(pin) == (4 or 6)` is different than the question to which my question as stated as duplicate of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because according to precedence rules, the right hand side expression is evaluated first in your first condition i.e.

`len(pin) == (4 or 6)`

Here, first `(4 or 6)` is evaluated and returns 4 (or true in some languages). Now, only those cases return true where `length` actually is 4.

Your second condition works as expected, because it compares the length to 4 and 6 both separately and then applies an `or` on both the boolean values.

Comment: Okay, now I understand. Thanks